# How to update at every call of MongoDB update?

Tags: mongodb, pymongo

I use pymongo to make some updades in MongoDB:

```
urlCollection.update({"_id":url["_id"]},{"$set":{"processed":1}})
```

this has effect in just half of calls.

**Mongo version: 2.0.2**

Comment: Really not much of an edit. Can you pleas answer the question I asked you? Your question is not clear.

Comment: It's about mongo matching the record for update

Answer (score 1):

If the issue is in the `_id`, this might solve your problem

```
from bson.objectid import ObjectId
urlCollection.update({"_id": ObjectId(url["_id"])},{"$set":{"processed":1}})
```